# Como calcular a distância entre dois pontos de localização?

Tags: ios, swift, geolocalização

Estou precisando calcular a distância mais curta entre duas localizações obtidas automaticamente através do `CoreLocation`.

Pra ser mais específico, a ideia é marcar um ponto inicial e depois do usuário "andar" um pouco, preciso calcular a distância percorrida quando chegar em outro local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir de dois objetos *CLLocation* você obtém a distância, em metros, atráves do método *distanceFromLocation*. Exemplo:

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
```

Comment: Interessante. Vou testar isso à noite. Só uma dúvida, essa distância é calculada com base em quê? Linha reta? Rotas?

Comment: Na maioria dos casos é praticamente uma linha reta. O método considera apenas a curvatura da terra. Para pontos próximos isso não vai fazer diferença. 
A documentação diz: "This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account specific altitude changes between the two locations."

Comment: funcionou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda